# Как отобразить картинку из byte[] во вьюшке в img

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, изображения

Как отображать картинки(массив байтов) в вьюшке(`<img>`)?

Допустим есть контроллер, в нем я получаю из базы данных массив байтов-картинку. Как я могу отобразить эти картинки во вьюшке. Буду рад услышать все возможные варианты

Comment: Зависит от того, как первоначальная картинка была преобразована в массив байтов.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вариант Виталия рабочий, но я предлагаю не морочиться с кодированием в base64 - а сразу отдавать картинку:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
{
    var image = System.IO.File.OpenRead("C:\\images\\myImage.jpeg"); // Или из базы, но я предпочитаю не грузить в БД картинки
    return File(image, "image/jpeg");
}
```

И использовать этот url в качестве обычно src у картинки — используя Url.Action или какая там у вас версия mvc.

```
<img src='@Url.Action(actionaname","controller")'>
```

В реальности, это [будет](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1759189/5752652) конечно action с параметром id картинки или её имени.

Разницы в подходах особо нет, ну разве что в base64 трафик будет на ~ 30% выше, чем если передавать последовательность байт. Насколько это критично с вашим объёмом картиночного трафика — решайте сами.

Ссылки по теме:

- [Отправка файлов в ASP.NET MVC 5](https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/3.6.php)
- [Return jpeg image from Asp.Net Core WebAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40794275/5752652)

Comment: а мне удобнее в БД хранить) Но всё равно спасибо за ваш ответ)

Answer (score 3):

```
using System;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using System.Linq;  
using System.Web;  
using System.Web.Mvc;  

namespace DemoProject.Controllers  
{  
    public class DemoController : Controller  
    {  
        // GET: Demo/GetImageFromByteArray  
        public ActionResult GetImageFromByteArray()  
        {    
            // Конвертируем 
            string imreBase64Data = Convert.ToBase64String(byteData);  
            string imgDataURL = string.Format("data:image/png;base64,{0}", imreBase64Data);  
            //Передаем во вью 
            ViewBag.ImageData = imgDataURL;  
            return View();  
        }  
    }  
}


@{  
    ViewBag.Title = "Asp.Net MVC Display image from byte array";  
}  

<h2>Asp.Net MVC Display image from byte array</h2>  
<img src="@ViewBag.ImageData">
```