# Получение информации из базы данных в мобильном приложении

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, asp.net-core, xamarin

Всем привет!
Я разработала веб-приложение на asp.net core 2 mvc, пока только на локалке, связала его с базой данных на sql при помощи entity framework, теперь, мне нужно разработать мобильное приложение, наверное буду делать его на Xamarin, и у меня вопрос, каким образом сделать так, что бы мое мобильное приложение получало данные из базы данных веб-приложения. Насколько я понимаю, нужно разработать API, можно ли его сделать в проекте веб-приложения, не переделывая методы получения данных в контроллерах, или все придется переделывать? И как лучше вообще решить мою проблему?
Всем спасибо)))

Comment: Мало информации. Если под веб-приложением вы имеете в виду некоторое API, то у вас всё готово. Если у вас там сайт и приложение не умеет отдавать JSON на запросы, то надо это сделать.

Comment: у меня просто сайт, как делать api я не знаю, json тоже не отдает)) я новичок в этом, мобильное приложение делаю впервые)

Comment: не могли бы вы поэтапно расписать, что нужно сделать?))

Comment: Сайт и API это одно и тоже. Оба на запросы по определённым адресам выдают информацию в виде строки. Отличие только в форматировании этой информации. В случае сайта это `HTML`, в случае API (нормального) - `JSON`. Т.е. вам надо на стороне серверного приложения добавить методы, которые будут отдавать информации из БД в виде `JSON`. После этого из мобильного приложения получать эту информацию.

Comment: не могли бы вы написать ссылки на статьи по данной теме?)

Comment: насколько я понимаю, сами контроллеры на сайте мне переделывать не надо, нужно добавить методы, и после этого нужно связать мобильное приложение с сайтом?)

Comment: Смотрите ответ ниже) Там человек разбирается, а я могу только общие вещи сказать, т.к. с C# дел не имел)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приложение asp.net core mvc отдаёт данные прямо в браузер в формате html. Для мобильных приложений нужен вывод ваших данных в формате json.

Можете создать дополнительно к каждому контроллеру по такому же контроллеру, который отдаёт/принимает данные в формате json.

Посмотрите [пустой проект Webapi](https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc/12.1.php) который идёт вместе со студией, какой там приведён контроллер ValuesController. Ничего сверхественного - даже в чём-то проще, выдаёте данные в типах c# их на лету превратит в json:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace WebApi.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        // GET api/values
        [HttpGet]
        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        // GET api/values/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public ActionResult<string> Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // POST api/values
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult<string> Post([FromBody] string value)
        {
            return $"value={value}.";
        }

        // PUT api/values/5
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody] string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/values/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }

        [Authorize]
        [Route("getlogin")]
        public IActionResult GetLogin()
        {
            return Ok($"Ваш логин: {User.Identity.Name}");
        }

        [Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
        [Route("getrole")]
        public IActionResult GetRole()
        {
            return Ok("Ваша роль: администратор");
        }
    }
}
```

Во-вторых, решите вопрос как ваше приложение будет авторизовываться на веб-апи, обычно для этого подходят jwt токен и хорошая входная точка - [вот тут](https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/23.7.php) и [вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/851781/213987), с этого многие начинали.

Я часто делаю приложения, которые одновременно являются и веб-сайтами и отдают данные по api (просто складываю api контроллеры в отдельную area).

Comment: спасибо большое)) надеюсь у меня получиться))

Comment: @Евгения Появятся более точечные вопросы - спрашивайте. Но мне кажется, вам надо сначала попробовать немного [ксамарин](https://metanit.com/sharp/xamarin/) поизучать в связке с asp.net core webapi.

Comment: Здравствуйте, у меня появился более точный, я смогла настроить получение данных с api, спасибо, но не могу понять, как мне открыть на мобильном приложении файлы pdf, которые будут хранится на сервере, или хотя бы загрузить их) разрабатываю на Xamarin.Android

Comment: @Евгения Появился новый вопрос - создавайте новую тему. Пока могу из комментариев дать намёк в какую сторону двигаться: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/975828/213987 возможно вопрос и пропадёт. )